# IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch, parameter context

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to unit test the below function which uses kotlin coroutines

```
fun authenticateWithUserAndPassword(usernameOrEmail: String, password: String) {
        launchUI(strategy) {   //line 76
            view.showLoading()
            try {
                val token = retryIO("login") {
                    when {
                        settings.isLdapAuthenticationEnabled() ->
                            client.loginWithLdap(usernameOrEmail, password)
                        usernameOrEmail.isEmail() ->
                            client.loginWithEmail(usernameOrEmail, password)
                        else ->
                            client.login(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    }
                }
                val myself = retryIO("me()") { client.me() }
                myself.username?.let { username ->
                    val user = User(
                        id = myself.id,
                        roles = myself.roles,
                        status = myself.status,
                        name = myself.name,
                        emails = myself.emails?.map { Email(it.address ?: "", it.verified) },
                        username = username,
                        utcOffset = myself.utcOffset
                    )
                    localRepository.saveCurrentUser(currentServer, user)
                    saveCurrentServer.save(currentServer)
                    localRepository.save(LocalRepository.CURRENT_USERNAME_KEY, username)
                    saveAccount(username)
                    saveToken(token)
                    analyticsManager.logLogin(
                        AuthenticationEvent.AuthenticationWithUserAndPassword,
                        true
                    )
                    view.saveSmartLockCredentials(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    navigator.toChatList()
                }
            } catch (exception: RocketChatException) {
                when (exception) {
                    is RocketChatTwoFactorException -> {
                        navigator.toTwoFA(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        analyticsManager.logLogin(
                            AuthenticationEvent.AuthenticationWithUserAndPassword,
                            false
                        )
                        exception.message?.let {
                            view.showMessage(it)
                        }.ifNull {
                            view.showGenericErrorMessage()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                view.hideLoading()
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the definition of launchUI

```
fun launchUI(strategy: CancelStrategy, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job =
    MainScope().launch(context = strategy.jobs, block = block)
```

here is the cancel Strategy class

```
class CancelStrategy(owner: LifecycleOwner, val jobs: Job) : LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        owner.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy() {
        jobs.cancel()
    }
}
```

I am new with unit testing with coroutines and have written a very basic test for the above function to gets some hand on coroutine testing

```
   @Test
    fun authenticateUserSuccessfuly() = runBlocking {
        loginPresenter.setupView()
        loginPresenter.authenticateWithUserAndPassword("username", "password")
        verify(view).showLoading()
        verify(saveCurrentServer).save(currentServer)
    }
```

On running the test I am getting the following error If someone can suggest how to test the above function It will be a great help.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch, parameter context

    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
    at chat.rocket.android.util.extension.CoroutinesKt.launchUI(Coroutines.kt:15)
    at chat.rocket.android.authentication.login.presentation.LoginPresenter.authenticateWithUserAndPassword(LoginPresenter.kt:76)
    at chat.rocket.android.authentication.login.presentation.LoginPresenterTest$authenticateUserSuccessfuly$1.invokeSuspend(LoginPresenterTest.kt:101)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.kt:116)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:76)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:53)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:35)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at chat.rocket.android.authentication.login.presentation.LoginPresenterTest.authenticateUserSuccessfuly(LoginPresenterTest.kt:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: This is a very specific question and generally isn't good for stackoverflow, since others probably won't get much help out of it. That being said the error states *parameter context* is null. Meaning, the `strategy` instance that you're passing in simply has a null value for it's `jobs` field.

Comment: @gMale thanks for your input, but a basic working unit test for the above case will greatly help me and others who are new to coroutines unit testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write unit tests for kotlin coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603445/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-kotlin-coroutines)