# How to write unit tests for kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to unit test the kotlin coroutines. My project is following MVP pattern where the coroutines are used in the presenter like this:

```
fun authenticateWithUserAndPassword(usernameOrEmail: String, password: String) {
        launchUI(strategy) {
            view.showLoading()
            try {
                val token = retryIO("login") {
                    when {
                        settings.isLdapAuthenticationEnabled() ->
                            client.loginWithLdap(usernameOrEmail, password)
                        usernameOrEmail.isEmail() ->
                            client.loginWithEmail(usernameOrEmail, password)
                        else ->
                            client.login(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    }
                }
                val myself = retryIO("me()") { client.me() }
                myself.username?.let { username ->
                    val user = User(
                        id = myself.id,
                        roles = myself.roles,
                        status = myself.status,
                        name = myself.name,
                        emails = myself.emails?.map { Email(it.address ?: "", it.verified) },
                        username = username,
                        utcOffset = myself.utcOffset
                    )
                    localRepository.saveCurrentUser(currentServer, user)
                    saveCurrentServer.save(currentServer)
                    localRepository.save(LocalRepository.CURRENT_USERNAME_KEY, username)
                    saveAccount(username)
                    saveToken(token)
                    analyticsManager.logLogin(
                        AuthenticationEvent.AuthenticationWithUserAndPassword,
                        true
                    )
                    view.saveSmartLockCredentials(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    navigator.toChatList()
                }
            } catch (exception: RocketChatException) {
                when (exception) {
                    is RocketChatTwoFactorException -> {
                        navigator.toTwoFA(usernameOrEmail, password)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        analyticsManager.logLogin(
                            AuthenticationEvent.AuthenticationWithUserAndPassword,
                            false
                        )
                        exception.message?.let {
                            view.showMessage(it)
                        }.ifNull {
                            view.showGenericErrorMessage()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                view.hideLoading()
            }
        }
    }
```

Here launchUI is defined as

```
/**
 * Launches a coroutine on the UI context.
 *
 * @param strategy a CancelStrategy for canceling the coroutine job
 */
fun launchUI(strategy: CancelStrategy, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job =
    MainScope().launch(context = strategy.jobs, block = block)
```

CancelStrategy class

```
class CancelStrategy(owner: LifecycleOwner, val jobs: Job) : LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        owner.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy() {
        jobs.cancel()
    }
}
```

I am new to coroutine unit testing and tried writing a basic unit test

```
@Test
fun check_authentication_of_user() = runBlocking {
    loginPresenter.authenticateWithUserAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    verify(navigator).toChatList()
}
```

On running the test I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch, parameter context
```

Any help regarding how to unit test the given method will be appreciated.

Comment: My very first thought when looking at your code from the clean code perspective: "this ain't no clean code". Your poor method is doing way too many things. And thing is: the more things one method is doing, the harder it becomes to test. So, not beig an expert on Kotlin (coroutines), my first suggestion would be: see if it is possible to improve your code, for example along the "Single Layer of Abstraction" or "Single Responsibility Principle". Also note: if you manage to dissect the large method into many smaller ones, those might be much easier to test. ...

Comment: And then you might only need some sort of integration test for the bit method that invokes the to-be-written smaller methods. The other important part: as said, focus on responsibilities. Try to *separate* the concern of parallelism (coroutines) from the actual purpose of your code. Meaning: you better find a way to test the "pure function" completely on its own. And then you simply have to ensure that the "coroutinish" stuff around that already tested method works by its own.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you but the current situation for me is to test the same method with minimum refactoring if possible. A simple basic test would work for me. Is their a way to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt\_\_Builders\_commonKt.launch, parameter context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56250508/illegalargumentexception-parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null-method-kotlin)